# iOS: How to disable webkit's just in time optimization of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webkit, jit

I have some Javascript that runs fast the first time, but the at normal speed every subsequent time.

Is there a way to tell Webkit to *not* optimize the Javascript, because it appears that the JIT is taking up too much time, resulting in a rushed execution of the code.

Note, I am using setInterval(function..., 20) and it is this every-20ms part (an animation) that is getting sped up.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to tell the interpreter how to behave. JavaScript doesn't have directives.

Comment: Is there a way to induce it to optimize all routines before anything gets run?

Comment: I don't think you can tell the interpreter how to optimize the code in Webkit. However, Rhino does have a feature to make use of the JVM to optimize JavaScript code. It's called the optimization level, and it can be set to an integer between -1 and 9 inclusive AFAIK.